# Filter pyspark dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need help because I wanted to filter some data from a dataframe as a criterion for another dataframe but I didn't want to use SQL commands.

```
df1

id ; create ; change ; name
1  ;2020-12-01;;Paul
2  ;2020-12-02;;Mary
3  ;2020-12-03;;David
4  ;2020-12-04;;Marley


df2
id ; create ; change ; name
1  ;2020-12-01;2020-12-30;Paul
2  ;2020-12-02;;Mary
3  ;2020-12-03;;David
4  ;2020-12-04;2020-12-30;Marley
5  ;2020-12-30;;Ted
```

df3

I wanted to create the df3 dataframe with the following rule where the id (df2) containing change pre-filled with the date 2020-12-30 and exists
in df1 not to be inserted in df3

```
id ; create ; change ; name
2  ;2020-12-02;;Mary
3  ;2020-12-03;;David
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first do a semi-join of `df2` with `df1`, and then filter the `change` column.

```
df3 = df2.join(df1, ['id', 'create', 'name'], 'semi') \
         .filter("change is null or change != '2020-12-30'") \
         .select('id', 'create', 'change', 'name')

df3.show()
+---+----------+------+-----+
| id|    create|change| name|
+---+----------+------+-----+
|  2|2020-12-02|  null| Mary|
|  3|2020-12-03|  null|David|
+---+----------+------+-----+
```